# How can I find out what RGB colors a website uses?

Tags: website-design, color, cmyk, rgb

I want to learn the RGB (or others like hex, CMYK or HSL) details of a color on a website. Say the background of this very website. I want to recreate that color using the code or a graphics software.

Comment: Do you specifically need CMYK? Because it's used for print, but for web RGB is all you need.

Comment: If you are using a MAC, there is always the digital color meter that is native to OSX and found under the Utilities folder in Applications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per thebodzio's answer, there's plenty of ways to get that colour. No matter what browser you use there will be some sort of colour picker add-on you can get. Alternatively you could take a screen shot and open it in photoshop. Another way is to open developer tools and look at the sites stylesheet, in chrome you could right click the background and hit inspect element then look for where the background colour is being specified...

To save you the trouble though, the background colour on that website is #f9f9f9 - now, if you're not too experienced with CSS, you might want to head over to the site, inspect the background colour and see if you can find where I got that from :)

Answer (score 5):

As to the page elements (excluding images), their colour (in RGB, sometimes in HSL) can be determined in a lot of different ways. One of the easiest is using any “developer tools” available in almost every contemporary web browser (Firefox, Chrome etc.). Colours in images can be sampled with any image editor having a tool like “colour picker”.

Having said that… It's not enough just to “get the RGB colour” and convert it to, say, CMYK. The tricky thing is to know which RGB and which CMYK you want to convert to and how do you want to deal with the outside-of-the-target-gamut colours. Yes, there's more than one RGB or CMYK. It's often silently assumed that when nothing is said about colour beside it being RGB, then it's really sRGB colour.

Anyway, I strongly recommend you to take a look at some introductory material about colour management. http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/color-management-printing.htm is one of the best around.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to get the colors from any website webpage etc....

1) Using Browser Color Picker Add-ons e.g [ColorZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorzilla/)

2) Take screenshot of your webpage by using **Print Screen button** on your keyboard and paste that image in Photoshop or any other image editing software and pick color from there with color picker tool

You can also use browser add-on like [Fireshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/) to take screenshot of whole webpage and take colors from anywhere on that page

Comment: ColorZilla is brilliant. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Chrome you can simply hit F12 and show the page elements.  On the right are the page styles  which use the Hexadecimal codes for colours.  These in turn translate into RGB colours.

For example if I scroll down a short way on the styles tab I can see that the background colour for the page is #f4f4f4.  The equivalent RGB colour is: R: 244 G: 244 B: 244

It also show the pattern image and tells me it's a repeat etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are some colour picker add-on for all Browsers
2. There are some websites that will find the colours of your website
    http://www.checkmycolours.com/

   http://html-color-codes.info
3. Take a screenshot and open in Photoshop or Gimp you can pick the colours

Answer (score 1):

I always use [Colorzilla](http://colorzilla.com/) for this type of thing. It's a neat extension that lets you select colors directly from any page and gives you the color in different formats.

Also, just as a bonus, there is [Web Colour Data](http://webcolourdata.com/) which gives you the color palette used on a given website.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Chrome extensions/Firefox add-ons, [ColorCop](http://colorcop.net/) is a lightweight Windows desktop application that does the same thing. It can generate RGB and hex values of the colors you'd like to get using a sampling tool.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new ['Eyedropper'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Eyedropper) tool included with Firefox that lets you point at a pixel, view the colour hex value, and copy it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve so, like taking a screenshot using *Print Screen* button and pasting that into MS Paint *(I am considering MS Paint as that's the default software anyone will have if working on a Windows machine)*, and use *Color Picker*

[image]

Once you do that, click on the color you want to get the `rgb` value.. and then click on *Edit Colors* option..

[image]

And you will get a modal with the information of the colors

[image]

---

Other way to achieve this is way easier than the above option, is to use a Color Picker plugin, I use [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/) for Firefox

Here, you will get a simple color picker on the AddOn bar, you need to click on that and you will get a Cross Hair cursor, click on the color you want to get the information for and you will get the below...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The little tool that I like to figure out colors is called Pixie, from Nattyware.com. It's free, tiny, very simple. Used it for years. Runs as a service; just click on a color and a window pops up and tells you hex, RGB, HTML, CMYK and HSV, plus mouse coordinates. Windows only.